# How to get distinct columns clientid and code grouped together by latest date?

Tags: t-sql, select, group-by, distinct, aggregate-functions

I have the table as following:

```
clientid   code  band   date
49          1    2-59   1899.12.01
49          1    2-54   2004.11.01
49          1    0-54   2013.05.17
49          2    60-64  1899.12.01
49          2    55-59  2004.11.01
49          3    65-69  1899.12.01
49          3    60-64  2004.11.01
```

How can I get distinct (clientid and code) by latest date.

For example, after executing solution I have to get the following table:

```
clientid   code  band   date
49          1    0-54   2013.05.17
49          2   55-59   2004.11.01
49          3   60-64   2004.11.01
```

It is logical that I have to use `MAX(date)` and `GROUP BY (clientid, code)`. This logic seems correct, but when I execute it it gives me an error that band is not included in GROUP BY. However, I cannot include band to GROUP BY because it is not going to sort correctly.

Following is the code that I have implemented so far.

```
SELECT clientid, code, band, MAX(date)
FROM tempTeble
GROUP BY clientid, code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery that will be correlated with a main query.Try this:

```
SELECT clientid, code, band, date
FROM tempTable t
WHERE date = (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM tempTable t2
    WHERE t2.clientid = t.clientid AND t2.code = t.code)
```

The subquery finds max date for every combination of *clientid* and *code*. The main query returns only these records for every combination of *clientid* and *code* for which *date* is equal to max date (that was found by the subquery).

Answer (score 0):

My solution using common table expression

```
WITH cte as
(
SELECT clientid,code,MAX(date) AS date from tempTable
GROUP BY clientid,code
)
SELECT t.* 
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN tempTable t
ON c.clientid=t.clientid
AND c.code=t.code
AND c.date=t.date
```

For variety,It can also be done using join

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tempTable t1 
JOIN (SELECT clientid,code,MAX(date) AS date from tempTable GROUP BY clientid,code) t2
ON t1.clientid=t2.clientid
AND t1.code=t2.code
AND t1.date=t2.date
```